# Is there a timestamp feature in GTM event data?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm creating an event data via GTM, and typically if it's sent to GA the timezone will follow the GA timezone but if I sent it to a different endpoint how do I capture the timestamp for the GTM event? Would I have to populate it in the dataLayer?

Comment: Will a custom variable work for you? With a very small script you can get the timestamp and use it wherever you need it. Let me know if you want me to elaborate further.

Comment: Yes could use more clarification on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a custom variable using javascript. That custom variable will return the current timestamp (beware that you may need to [deal with browsers timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone), if that is important to you).

Go to Variables and add a new using the type Custom JavaScript:
[image]

Then the code could be along this lines ([grabbed from here](https://gtm.tips/add-timestamp-ga-events/)), depending on the format you want to return:

```
function() {
 try {
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var time = timestamp.toString().split(' ');
  return time[3]+ " " +time[1]+ " " +time[2]+ " "+time[4];
 } catch(e) {
  return "unknown";
 }
}
```

After that, a variable with the name given (in this case I used 'Timestamp') will become available as `{{Timestamp}}` You then can plug it in the event or whatever tag you are creating. You may even use it as `{{Timestamp}}` inside a Javascript tag. The variable will return a timestamp in the format: `2020 May 30 11:41:44`